# Truncated ProcessName in Win32_ProcessStartTrace query

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm using this code to monitor process:

```
var startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
startWatch.EventArrived += startWatch_EventArrived;
startWatch.Start();

var stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace");
stopWatch.EventArrived += stopWatch_EventArrived;
stopWatch.Start();
```

Problem is - ProcessName property is truncated to 14 chars in both callbacks.

```
var name = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
```

Both processes (monitor and monitored) are x64 .NET console apps.

Anybody have any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Could you please provide a complete reproductible example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Just google "win32_processstarttrace process name truncated" for basic hits about this known problem.  The Linux bug report is pretty hilarious btw.  Anyhoo, the first hit shows the workaround, use the ProcessID property instead and then Process.GetProcessById() to get a better name.

Comment: Whole project to build http://www.filedropper.com/processmonitor

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, i guess i can't trust ProcessName :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [__InstanceCreationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/--instancecreationevent)/[__InstanceDeletionEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/--instancedeletionevent) instead

Example

```
var startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'");
startWatch.EventArrived += startWatch_EventArrived;
startWatch.Start();

var stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'");
stopWatch.EventArrived += stopWatch_EventArrived;
stopWatch.Start();
```

Event example

```
// e.NewEvent now have only 3 properties, we should focus on TargetInstance property
var targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject) e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
// TargetInstance has more than 40 properties, some properties can be null
var name = targetInstance["Name"]?.ToString();
```

Tested on .NET Core 3.1 with [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) NuGet package.

Before

```
// Win32_ProcessStartTrace
"League of Legends.exe"
// Win32_ProcessStopTrace
"League of Le" // How can this happen??? Like how???
```

After

```
// __InstanceCreationEvent
"League of Legends.exe"
// __InstanceDeletionEvent
"League of Legends.exe"
```

Comment: I honestly forgot what i was trying to achieve,  but your suggestion seems to be working great :D