# C# - Write ManagementEventWatcher query with condition?

Tags: c#, .net-core, wmi

What I have now is WMI watcher:

```
ManagementEventWatcher processStartEvent = 
  new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
```

**I need to filter the query by multiple process names** Whats the correct syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419865/3312570

Comment: I need complete syntax.. eg `WHERE field OP 'winword'` - what are `field` and `OP` would be or whatever..